# Legend colour with specific value

Tags: r, legend, color

I have model plotted in R

`base<- raster("example.tif")
 plot(base)`

[image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9unpss3t6el01es/1.png?dl=0)
I'd like to change value (0,5,10,15,20,25)

`breakpoints<-c("0,5,10,15,20,25")
 plot(base,break=breakpoints)`

Error in .rasterImagePlot(object, col = col, xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab,  : 
  object 'breakpoints' not found

I'd like make ramp(default colour)

Comment: Question: Please look at the colour legend in the attached image. This image was plotted in ferret program, which has different breaks, like 0-3 with 0.5 interval, 3-9 with 3 interval, 9-10 with 1 interval, 10-20 with 2 interval and 20-70 with 50 interval. The legend scale was uniformly graduated but labelled as per breaks given. Can we get such legends in R 'Raster - plot'?
or any other packages in R? Thanks :) Karnan C [![Satellite chlorophyll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCXYN.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCXYN.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using my base raster:

```
base<- raster("test.tif")
plot(base)
```

I got:

[image]

For your breakpoints:

```
breakpoints<-c(0,5,10,15,20,25)
plot(base, col=terrain.colors(6), breaks=breakpoints)
```

[image]

With **help(plot)**, raster option, you can see examples of other descriptions for this R command.

Another plot option:

```
plot(base, col=colorRampPalette(c("red", "orange", "blue"))(6), breaks=breakpoints)
```

where I have:

[image]

**Editing Note**:

I know that the values of my raster are between 0-50. I can do this:

```
breakpoints<-c(0,5,10,15,20,25,50)
plot(base, col=colorRampPalette(c("red", "orange", "blue"))(7), breaks=breakpoints)
```

or this:

```
breakpoints<-c(0,5,10,15,20,25,50)
colors<-c("red", "orange", "blue","green","yellow","cyan","magenta")
plot(base, col=colors, breaks=breakpoints)
```

[image]

Comment: For customized colors: "A color palette, i.e. a vector of n contiguous colors generated by functions like rainbow, heat.colors, topo.colors, bpy.colors or one or your own making, perhaps using colorRampPalette’. If none is provided,  ‘rev(terrain.colors(255))’ is used unless ‘x’ has a 'color table'"

Comment: Please, edit your question and put the complete code that you are using.

Comment: You have an error here: `breakpoints<-c("0,5,10,15,20,25")`. It is: `breakpoints<-c(0,5,10,15,20,25)`

Comment: Because your original values are between 0-60 and now, you have new labels values produced by your breakpoints. Can you change the aspect of the legend?

Comment: can >25 same color with 25 ?
and how to change min color value to max color value? [like this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z6bqlp8li8rtucg/231.png?dl=0)

Comment: Yes, its possible. I am going to modify my code and edit my answer.

Comment: @Yax I edited my answer. I hope that helps.

Comment: It works with only 6 color class. I added one more. Magenta color it's not necessary.

Comment: yes, i have other case:
original values are between 8-11.9
can i break (0,2,4,6,8,10) or (0,3,5,7,9,11) ?
with 10> or 11> same color with 10 or 11 ?
same code?

Comment: Try:

`breakpoints<-c(0,2,4,6,8,10,12)
colors<-c("red", "orange", "blue","green","cyan","cyan")
plot(base, col=colors, breaks=breakpoints)`

Comment: thanks a lot, but can like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bca1787we1a7aj3/2131.png?dl=0)
12 out of legend but color still follow

Comment: You do not need to create an object, just pass your break points and colors directly to the arguments in plot.